# AntChart Connect Null Values on Chart

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

[image]

I have a ant design chart, and sometimes you do not get values in some series but it is automaticly connect line with each other.

I already set connectNulls= false but this chart is making connection for null values.

```
const TestChart = (data) => {
const config = {
data,
xField: "id",
yField: "value",
connectNulls: false,
seriesField: "type",
colorField: "type",
color: type  };  
return <Line {...config} />;};
export default TestChart;
```

I think I am using it wrong or did not understand the situation. Could anyone help about it?
I do not want to connect lines if there is no value.

Comment: Solved: I specified null values if there is no value
   ` {
      year: '1997',
      value: 7,
    },
    {
      year: '1998',
      value: null,
    },
    {
      year: '1999',
      value: 13,
    },`